# Freebsd printing: Unable to print using lpd

Tags: freebsd, printing

i have setup the lpr for usb printer by following a guide from the web.. 
however, i have got the error

```
lpr: Error - no default destination available
```

Output from dmesg:

```
ulpt0: Canon Inc MF4800 Series, class 0/0, rev 2.00/1.00, addr 6 on usbus0
ulpt0: using bi-directional mode
```

/etc/printcap:

```
canon|local line printer:\
:lp=/dev/ulpt0:\
:af=/usr/local/etc/cups/ppd/Canon_MF4820d.ppd:\
:if=/usr/local/bin/foomatic-rip:\
:sh:\
:mx#0:\
:sd=/var/spool/output/canon:lf=/var/log/lpd-errs:
```

Performed the following:

```
# cd /var/spool/output
# mkdir canon
# chown bin canon
# chgrp daemon canon
# chmod 755 canon
```

Finally restarted the lpd.

```
sudo service lpd restart
Stopping lpd
Waiting for PIDS: 1478
Starting lpd
```

Any helpful feedback would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Justin

Comment: Did you try `lpr -Pcanon`?

Comment: i just tried.. still no go. And it returns this error "lpr: Bad file descriptor"

Comment: Uhm, please try `/usr/bin/lpr`! Did you install cups?

Comment: i tried /usr/bin/lpr.. and the error is "lpr: lp: unknown printer" Previously i did install CUPS, it did not work too. But after much research on the web, i realise that the CUPS has nothing to do with lpd, therefore i have removed it. Please correct me if i;m wrong. Thanks.

Comment: If i use "/usr/bin/lpr -Pcanon test.pdf" , there is no error and no printout too.

Comment: I have tried to follow the troubleshooting guide in https://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-print.html
but no output for the below even after putting on the input filter as described in the guide ( if=/usr/local/libexec/lpfilter)

lptest 70 5 > /dev/lpt0

Comment: I think your printer isn't `lpt0`. Your printer is `ulpt0` :) Please retry `lptest` ;)

Comment: okie, still no go even if i use ulpt0. I think i shall end this discussion right here since i believe it's not worth for the time just to resolve this issue. I might explore on the Samba alternative which might yearn  a fruitful result. Thanks for your advise, Steve.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that no default destination exists.

To quote from the [`printcap(5)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=printcap&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) manpage:

```
The default printer is normally lp, though  the environment variable
PRINTER may be used to override this.  Each spooling utility supports an
option, -P  printer, to allow explicit naming of a destination printer.
```

So either change the first line of your printcap entry to

```
lp|canon|local line printer:\
```

or set the variable PRINTER to "canon" or "local line printer".

Unfortunately I can't tell what else is wrong here. :(